# Grub won't load, stuck in BIOS loop

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios

So basically, I had ubuntu 18,04 installed with windows (dual boot) for about 4 months. When i booted the PC it automatically loaded GRUB in the past. Now when i boot the pc up it automatically always go to the bios no matter what. I tried to switch the boot priority order so it would boot to a boot-repair USB key(that i flashed), it didnt, i tried to boot from the windows boot manager, it didnt. No matter what device i put in what order in the boot priority order, it always go to the bios regardless.

Boot mode is set in UEFI, i set the shimx64.efi to trusted, i disabled secure boot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? It seems more like an UEFI issue as if Windows or live installer does not boot, then not a grub issue. And Update to UEFI reset some settings to defaults, or sometimes Windows updates would reset UEFI and back to defaults. But then Windows still should boot.If you have not updated UEFI, I might try that first, and then make sure your UEFI settings are what you want.

Comment: Weirdly, i flashed an ISO image of ubuntu on an bootable usb device, changed my boot order so the USB device would boot first and ubuntu(well GRUB first) booted normally... And when i removed the USB device and changed is so it would boot from the .efi file, it did everything normally.. as if booting ubuntu once from an USB device fixed everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I basically ran out of solutions, couldn't boot from USB, EFI file, HDD, Windows boot manager. So I decided that the 2 remaining solutions was to

1. Try to clean install Ubuntu from an USB device
2. Hard reset the BIOS through the CMOS memory and clean install whatever OS.

So I flashed an Ubuntu Image on a bootable USB device and booted from it in the BIOS, and it loaded GRUB perfectly! So I rebooted it with the shimx64.efi file in first boot priority and it booted just fine from there! So I think that I'm always going to carry a bootable USB stick with a fresh Linux distro on it if any problems happens to me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Grub Customizer:**

Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the `grub2`. The application allows the user to add, remove, freeze, rename and reorder boot menu items.

Open up terminal by hitting `Ctrl+Alt+T` and run following commands one by one:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

**How to use?**

- Once installed, hit Gnome dash and search for "G" and double-click
  `Grub-customizer` icon to open up.
  [image]
  `Figure-1: Type 'G' in search box in order to cause 'Grub customizer' to appear`
- `Grub Customizer` will always request you for authentication. Type
  your `sudo` password.
  [image]
  `Figure-2: Type sudo password authentication`
- Now using this graphical tool you change the boot order of GRUB by
  bringing up Windows bootloader to the top of the chain. This can be
  done by moving the desired loader up until it reaches the top.
  [image]
  `Figure-3: Place the cursor on 'Windows bootloader', then right click for drop down menu to appear and use 'move up' menu item to lift 'Windows bootloader' up in the ladder until you park it on the top.`
- Once `Windows bootloader` parked at the top of the ladder, the first
  thing you should do is save the settings. There is a `save` menu item
  at the top-left and click that to save your GRUB configuration. You
  should never ignore this step!
- So by default windows-10 which you have set will be booted after 10
  seconds. Just click `General settings` marked by a red arrow to get
  the following figure-4, where you can alter this 10 seconds delay
  interval.
  [image]
  `Figure-4: GRUB interval 10 seconds may be altered here`
- You can always  explore this tool without any fear because you can
  always `quit` from the tool without saving!
- This is how you configure Grub using Grub Customizer tool. Very reliable!

@Samuel Bouchard, you try to correct your GRUB issue using this tool. If you find any difficulty, you just contact me and get help!

Comment: Very nice guide but unfortunately useless in answering this question.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, Grub Customizer tool is useful in detecting and rectifying GRUB related issues. In this case, even if `useless`, this tools helps in establishing the fact that the issue in hand is non-GRUB related. You can look around for more answers!

Comment: My point is it doesn't matter what and how you customize Grub if Grub itself and consequently Ubuntu isn't loading. This does not answer the question not provides any useful solution.

Comment: The questioner of this post Samuel Bouchard himself addressed in his most recent concluding comment that `everything fixed after booted once from USB device`. I observed that this post is one of strange one and my attempts to answer were  not all significant or relevant in this case. But it does not mean that we should shrink ourselves from extending helping hands in spite of our contribution did not help. I always try with best intentions and never support any scams. Hope you see my point @GabrielaGarcia.